# How it is possible to clear the textbox in the web page using html element

Tags: c#, browser

I am trying to write email on a web page. But, I want to clear the textbox boefore writing on page. Because, if any other email is there in the textbox, the below code is not working.

How it is possible to clear the textbox in the web page using html element?

```
HtmlElement ele = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("email"); 
if (ele != null)
    ele.InnerText = "myacc@gmail.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the value attribute for clearing it

Answer (score 0):

hmm... if you mean textfield & javascript code:

```
<input type="text" id="email">
```

then you can use simply smth like this:

```
document.getElementById('email').value = 'myacc@gmail.com';
```

or i am misunderstanding your question.

P.S. Oops. It seems not like javascript, sry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ele.SetAttribute("value", "");
```

Another option is to use `Document.InvokeScript` to call a Javascript function that clears the text box.